# How to use multiple filter in $filter Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I have two filter which need to applied on the content of controller. First filter will be lowercase and other one is custom filter.

I tried to use it like follows:

```
$filter('lowercase','cardShortNameRegex')(currentProductObject.shortName);
```

Only lowercase filter get applied not the other one.

if some one have any solution or suggestion please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call it one after another.

```
var lowerCasedName = $filter('lowercase')(currentProductObject.shortName);
var result = $filter('cardShortNameRegex')(lowerCasedName);
```

You can also define your own function something like this:

```
var result = multipleFilters('lowercase', 'cardShortNameRegex')(currentProductObject.shortName);

function multipleFilters() {
  var filters = arguments;
  return function (input) {
    angular.forEach(filters, function (filterName) {
      input = $filter(filterName)(input);
    });
    return input;
  }
}
```

which accepts multiple filter names and applies them.

Comment: Is there any other way available? If there is any single line solution for it that will be good because I have to do it many places for different conditions.

Comment: @Toretto I updated my answer with another possible solution